# javascript make a new class

Tags: javascript, class

I have some code for load an object in to javascript/three js.
This code I want to have in a differnt class so I have a smaller code.

The following code I want to have in a class

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {};

var texture = new THREE.Texture();
var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
    }
};
var onError = function ( xhr ) {};

var loaderA = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
loaderA.load('sig.png', function ( image ) {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
});

var loaderB = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loaderB.load( 'hoesjes/hoes.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.material.map = texture;
        }
    } );

    this.objectLoader.position.x = xpos;
    this.objectLoader.position.y = ypos;
    this.objectLoader.position.z = zpos;  

    object.position.y = - 20;
    scene.add( object );
}, onProgress, onError );

}
```

Is it right if I make an class with constructor like below?

```
class objectLoader

constructor(xpos, ypos, zpos) {
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {};
    var texture = new THREE.Texture();

    var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
        if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
        }
    };
    var onError = function ( xhr ) {};

    var loaderA = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
    loaderA.load('sig.png', function ( image ) {
        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
    } );

    var loaderB = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    loaderB.load( 'hoesjes/hoes.obj', function ( object ) {
        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material.map = texture;
            }
        } );
        this.objectLoader.position.x = xpos;
        this.objectLoader.position.y = ypos;
        this.objectLoader.position.z = zpos;  

        object.position.y = - 20;
        scene.add( object );
    }, onProgress, onError );
}
```

}

If this is right how do I call it on my mainpage? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code to be readable

Comment: My bad, now its better

Comment: Protip: if you want the site to be publicly viewable later, then don't use ES6. It's not supported in some browsers (like in Safari).

Comment: buddy.constructor are not for these things and not even class if u writing such such way.Read some tutorials to get idea on class